# Controller and view don't show the same when viewing entity fields

Tags: doctrine, twig, symfony

I work on Symfony3, I have a problem with two entities :

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MainBundle\Entity\Tournament", inversedBy="currentUsers")
 */
private $currentTournamentUsed;
...
}


class Tournament
{
...

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="currentTournamentUsed")
 */
private $currentUsers;

...

}
```

I successfully create a User, a Tournament. Both are correctly linked in DB.

When I access the `currentTournamentUsed` from User in Controller (like this :)

```
echo $user->getCurrentTournamentUsed()->getName();
```

OK.

But when I do the same in Twig (like this:)

```
{{ app.user.getCurrentTournamentUsed.getName }}
```

I get nothing printed.

Any idea of what could cause this/how to debug it ?

Regards

Comment: How do you get $user in controller?

Comment: $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
    $user = $token->getUser();

Comment: Did you try to dump your data `{{dump( app.user.currentTournamentUsed) }}` ?

Comment: I tried to dump. Very weird results. All the fields or the `Tournament` entity are `null` (which is not normal ; the object is OK in DB), except for the relationship with `User` that is OK.

Comment: can you show your controller code that posts the render to the twig? It'll be something like: `return $this->render('path_to_twig_file', array('form' => $form->createView(),...` or something like this. It might no be a form though.

Comment: @Alvin Bunk Actually, the twig part that doesn't work is a sidebar included in every page. For instance, here is one render instruction : `return $this->render('MainBundle:Tournament:create.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));`

Comment: That means you haven't passes 'app' to it and it will be null. Your array in the render should be something like: `return $this->render('MainBundle:Tournament:create.html.twig', array( 'form' => $form->createView(), 'app' => $some_user_object ));` This is presuming that 'app' represents a User object.

Comment: @AlvinBunk According to the doc : 'The `app` variable is available everywhere and gives access to many commonly needed objects and values. It is an instance of GlobalVariables.' No need to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest that in twig you should use either `{{ app.user.getCurrentTournamentUsed().getName() }}` or `{{ app.user.currentTournamentUsed.name }}`

Comment: @Jeremie what if you add `@JoinColumn(name="tournament_id", referencedColumnName="id")` annotation to $currentTournamentUsed?

Comment: Doesn't change anything